# Lifetime of connections when using CURL_LOCK_DATA_CONNECT

Tags: libcurl

I currently have a system that uses the `easy` APIs and multiple threads to achieve request parallelization. As an optimization, a shared connection cache is used via the sharing interface and `CURL_LOCK_DATA_CONNECT`.

I know that when using the `easy` interface, each connection pool is associated with a specific handle. So if the handle goes away, so does the associated connection pool.

When using a shared connection cache, is there still an association between the cache entry and the handle? In other words, are connections removed from the cache when the associated handles are destroyed? Or are the lifetime of the connections within the shared connection cache completely independent of the handles?

For what it's worth, I will switch to the `multi` interface in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using the [`CURL_LOCK_DATA_CONNECT` option](https://curl.se/libcurl/c/CURLSHOPT_SHARE.html) with a shared object, the connection cache is indeed shared among different `easy` handles. The purpose of this is to enable connection re-use across different easy handles, effectively pooling these connections.

In this shared setup, when an `easy` handle is destroyed, the connections associated with that handle will not be immediately discarded if they are in the shared connection pool. They will remain available for other `easy` handles to re-use, depending on the connection reuse policy `libcurl` employs, which factors in things like destination, credentials, etc.

That is why, for instance, you had [`curl/curl` issue 4544](https://github.com/curl/curl/issues/4544): "`CURL_LOCK_DATA_CONNECT` can cause concurrent access to a connection on multiple threads", fixed with [Pr 4557](https://github.com/curl/curl/pull/4557) in curl 7.68.0 (Dec. 2019).

However, it is important to note that just because a connection is kept in the pool, it does not necessarily mean it stays alive indefinitely. Connections in the pool that are not actively in use can be closed due to reasons like the server closing the connection, network issues.

`CURL_LOCK_DATA_CONNECT` comes with curl 7.57.0 (Nov. 2017), and [PR 2043](https://github.com/curl/curl/pull/2043)

You can see the [official example `shared-connection-cache.c`](https://github.com/curl/curl/blob/47a3e6e577b019b8dfce8d3f8df764a8dd427fd2/docs/examples/shared-connection-cache.c), which calls [`lib/easy.c#curl_easy_cleanup()`](https://github.com/curl/curl/blob/47a3e6e577b019b8dfce8d3f8df764a8dd427fd2/lib/easy.c#L790) and [`lib/share.c#curl_share_cleanup()`](https://github.com/curl/curl/blob/47a3e6e577b019b8dfce8d3f8df764a8dd427fd2/lib/share.c#L211)

I do not see a "lifetime", beside [closing the connection](https://github.com/curl/curl/blob/master/lib/url.c#L344-L351), which does clean the easy handles.

In general, transitioning to the `multi` interface might be beneficial because it was specifically designed to handle multiple connections efficiently, and you will not need to manage threads yourself. The connection pooling and reuse will still work similarly with `CURL_LOCK_DATA_CONNECT` on a shared object.

Comment: Thanks. Somehow I missed the official example; but comment in that code is the exact type of smoking gun I was looking for: "Loop the transfer and cleanup the handle properly every lap. This will still reuse connections since the pool is in the shared object!"